# Change User's Password using root

Tags: linux, user-accounts, passwd

How can I change password of specific user using root account?
when you want to change your password, you can use `passwd` but how can I change the password of other users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go:

`passwd USERNAME`

...

Comment: The password is changed but I have to reboot the hosts? Any idea?

Comment: No need to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Here see below...
syntax and picture...

## passwd [username]

Changing local password for [username]

New Password:

Retype New Password:

[image]